# Apex trigger to create custom object on Opportunity Update

Tags: apex, trigger

Afternoon all,

I've created a trigger to create a new custom object when an Opportunity reaches 50% Probability and above. I've also created a test class for it which passes. It's just not working and I can't see why, can anyone offer any advice?

My trigger

```
trigger CreateImpTrackerOnProbabilityIncrease on Opportunity (after update) {
    List <Implementation_Log__c> impToCreate = new list <Implementation_Log__c>();
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        if (o.Probability > 0.49) {
        Implementation_Log__c i = new Implementation_Log__c ();
        i.Opportunity_Name__c = o.Id;
        i.Implementation_Owner__c = 'To Be Assigned';
        i.Implementation_Status__c = 'Consultant to update';

        insert impToCreate;
        }
        }
        }
```

My test class

```
@isTest public class TestUpdateOpportunity {
    static testMethod void insertNewOpp() {
        Opportunity insertNewOpp = new Opportunity();
        insertNewOpp.Name = 'Test Opp';
        insertNewOpp.AccountID = '001m000000BsmZB';
        insertNewOpp.Type = 'New Busienss';
        insertNewOpp.Highlevel_Product_Type__c= 'Breakdown';
        insertNewOpp.CloseDate = Date.today() + 15;
        insertNewOpp.Service_Live_Date__c = Date.today() + 16;
        insertNewOpp.StageName = '50% - Shortlisted';
        insertNewOpp.Deal_Term__c = '1 Year';
        insertNewOpp.Contract_Arrangement__c = 'New Contract';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Funding__c = 'None';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Indicative_Cost__c = '£0 - configuration only';

        insert insertNewOpp;
    }
    }
```

Thanks all

Comment: Is '001m000000BsmZB' the Id of known `Account` in the org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a list of issues with your code:

1. Tests, by default, do not see any data in your org, so the hardcoded Account Id '001m000000BsmZB', will not exist when the test is executing. You should not be using hardcoded Ids in tests
2. Your trigger is on `after update` but you do not update `Opportunity` in the test. Either change your test or change the trigger
3. You do not set the `Probability` on the `Opportunity` so it will never go into your `if` statement
4. You don't add any records to the `impToCreate` list so nothing will be inserted.
5. You are doing an `insert` in a `for loop` which will cause issues when multiple records are updated at once.
6. Your trigger runs anytime an `Opportunity` changes no matter what the change was. You should only be running your logic when certain things change e.g. when `Probability` changes

Here is an example of what your trigger could look like:

```
trigger CreateImpTrackerOnProbabilityIncrease on Opportunity (after update) {
    List <Implementation_Log__c> impToCreate = new list <Implementation_Log__c>();
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        if (o.Probability != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Probability && o.Probability > 0.49) {
            Implementation_Log__c i = new Implementation_Log__c ();
            i.Opportunity_Name__c = o.Id;
            i.Implementation_Owner__c = 'To Be Assigned';
            i.Implementation_Status__c = 'Consultant to update';
            impToCreate.add(i);
        }
    }
    insert impToCreate;
}
```

And here is a basic test that will set the probability and verify that the `Implementation_Log__c` object is created

```
@isTest public class TestUpdateOpportunity {
    static testMethod void insertNewOpp() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'TestName');
        insert a;

        Opportunity insertNewOpp = new Opportunity();
        insertNewOpp.Name = 'Test Opp';
        insertNewOpp.AccountID = a.Id;
        insertNewOpp.Type = 'New Busienss';
        insertNewOpp.Highlevel_Product_Type__c= 'Breakdown';
        insertNewOpp.CloseDate = Date.today() + 15;
        insertNewOpp.Service_Live_Date__c = Date.today() + 16;
        insertNewOpp.StageName = '50% - Shortlisted';
        insertNewOpp.Deal_Term__c = '1 Year';
        insertNewOpp.Contract_Arrangement__c = 'New Contract';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Funding__c = 'None';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Indicative_Cost__c = '£0 - configuration only';
        insert insertNewOpp;

        insertNewOpp.Probability = 0.50;
        update insertNewOpp;

        Implementation_Log__c il = [select Id from Implementation_Log__c];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, il);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, BarCotter, I couldn't see the wood for the trees. My logic behind the test class was just to update create an opportunity with the right probability value to start the trigger. I've tested the trigger in my sandbox and it's working, but not quite as anticipated. Updating the probability to any value is firing the trigger as opposed to only updates that push the probability to 50% or higher. Thoughts?

Also, would you mind explaining the bold bit of this?
       if (**o.Probability != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Probability** && o.Probability > 0.49) {

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. The Probability value of 0.49 needed to be 49. I've also introduced a Roll Up summary to count the number of child objects so it only fires where a child doesn't already exist. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't try to hard code in test classes since you can't guarantee when it'l be deleted.
2. Always try to [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) your triggers.
3. Apply some [assers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assert) in your test classes based on your use cases.

Below code will helpful for you. Please note that this is not tested. Update the code snippets as you need in your use cases.

Trigger :

```
trigger CreateImpTrackerOnProbabilityIncrease on Opportunity (after update) {
    List <Implementation_Log__c> impToCreate = new list <Implementation_Log__c>();
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        if (o.Probability > 0.49) {
            Implementation_Log__c i = new Implementation_Log__c ();
            i.Opportunity_Name__c = o.Id;
            i.Implementation_Owner__c = 'To Be Assigned';
            i.Implementation_Status__c = 'Consultant to update';

            impToCreate.add(i);
        }
    }

    insert impToCreate;
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest public class TestUpdateOpportunity {
    static testMethod void insertNewOpp() {
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert testAccount;

        Opportunity insertNewOpp = new Opportunity();
        insertNewOpp.Name = 'Test Opp';
        insertNewOpp.AccountID = testAccount.Id;
        insertNewOpp.Type = 'New Busienss';
        insertNewOpp.Highlevel_Product_Type__c= 'Breakdown';
        insertNewOpp.CloseDate = Date.today() + 15;
        insertNewOpp.Service_Live_Date__c = Date.today() + 16;
        insertNewOpp.StageName = '50% - Shortlisted';
        insertNewOpp.Deal_Term__c = '1 Year';
        insertNewOpp.Contract_Arrangement__c = 'New Contract';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Funding__c = 'None';
        insertNewOpp.IT_Change_Indicative_Cost__c = '£0 - configuration only';

        insert insertNewOpp;

        insertNewOpp.StageName = 'Something higher than 50%';
        update insertNewOpp;

        List<Implementation_Log__c> childList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Implementation_Log__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__c =: insertNewOpp.Id];

        System.assert(childLIst != null);
    }
}
```